# Run FFmpeg commands

Tags: amazon-s3, web-applications, ffmpeg

How can I use ffmpeg commands in my application? The ffmpeg commands work perfectly on my local machine, but ffmpeg.exe is installed locally. How would I make them work when running the application on the server. Can I have the ffmpeg.exe in the app directory, will that work?

I tried not to use command line instructions as much as possible, but to write text on a video, I had to use the drawtext instruction. Any ideas on how to use ffmpeg command when ffmpeg is installed only on your local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have ffmpeg accessible on the server . Are you sure to have access to ffmpeg ? if you use php to launch it, you must have right to launch ffmpeg ? have you these access ?